# Auto pairing MacBook with iPhone (networksetup)

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, wifi, tethering

I'm trying to automatically tether my MacBook to my iPhone (the laptop is too old to make use of Apple's proprietary features in this regard), but I can't seem to figure out how to make this happen via the terminal.

The obvious way to connect to wireless networks is

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork NETWORK_NAME NETWORK_PASS
```

When I call this with my credentials, however, I get

> Nick's iPhone is not a Wi-Fi interface.
>   ** Error: Error obtaining wireless information.

Are there any alternate ways to connect to networks? From what I can tell I can't do it with `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport`. Does anyone have experience with this?